# template specialization with struct in c++14

Tags: c++14, template-specialization

I am trying to write a specialized decay with template specialization on certain types:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct stateful_decay {
  using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
struct stateful_decay<T&&> {
  using type = T;
};

template <>
struct stateful_decay<PullTask&&> {
  using type = PullTask;
};

template <>
struct stateful_decay<PullTask&> {
  using type = PullTask;
};

template <>
struct stateful_decay<PullTask> {
  using type = PullTask;
};

template <>
struct stateful_decay<const PullTask&&> {
  using type = PullTask;
};
template <>
struct stateful_decay<const PullTask&> {
  using type = PullTask;
};

template <>
struct stateful_decay<const PullTask> {
  using type = PullTask;
};

template <typename T>
using stateful_decay_t = typename stateful_decay<T>::type;
```

Apparently, `PullTask` specialization has a lot of verbosity. Basically, any thing related to `PullTask` type should decay to `PullTask`. Is there any way to improve this? I am thinking about to use `std::decay_t` but didn't know how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct stateful_decay
    : std::conditional<std::is_same<PullTask, std::decay_t<T>>{}, PullTask, T> {};

template <typename T>
struct stateful_decay<T&&>
    : stateful_decay<T> {};

template <typename T>
using stateful_decay_t = typename stateful_decay<T>::type;
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fedd7ff53ff5ca2e)